# Angular JS routing no output

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and am doing the Dan Wahlin tutorial. Im using 1.4.4 for both Angular and Angular Route. But for some reason when I run the routing tutorial. I get no output

Here are the relevant code files:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" ng-app = 'app'>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
</head>
<body>

<div ng-view></div>

<script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/controllers/new_Controller.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

new_Controller.js

```
function Controller_people($scope) {
    $scope.person = [
        {
            name: 'Bob',
            gender: 'M',
            city: 'Cincinnati'
        },
        {
            name: 'Jacob',
            gender: 'M',
            city: 'Chicago'
        },
        {
            name: 'Tom',
            gender: 'M',
            city: 'New York'
        },
        {
            name: 'Jill',
            gender: 'F',
            city: 'Las Vegas'
        },
        {
            name: 'Elaine',
            gender: 'F',
            city: 'Hollywood'
        },
        {
            name: 'Hannah',
            gender: 'F',
            city: 'Miami'
        }];
    $scope.order = function (var_name) {
        $scope.sort_by = var_name;
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    }
}

Controller_people.$inject = ['$scope'];
angular.module('app', []).controller('Controller_people',Controller_people);
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config( function ($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',{
            controller: 'Controller_people',
            templateUrl: '/app/views/people.html'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
});
```

people.html

```
Search by Name: <input type="text" ng-model="filter_by.name">
Search by Gender: <input type="text" ng-model="filter_by.gender">
Search by City: <input type="text" ng-model="filter_by.city"><br>

Sort by Name: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="sort_by" ng-true-value="'name'">
Sort by Gender: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="sort_by" ng-true-value="'gender'">
Sort by City: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="sort_by" ng-true-value="'city'"><br>

<button ng-click="$scope.gender= 'M'">To view boys</button>
<button ng-click="$scope.gender= 'F'">To view girls</button>
<button ng-click="$scope.gender= 'A'">To view all</button>
<br/>
<br/>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th ng-click="order('name')">Name</th>
        <th ng-click="order('gender')">Gender</th>
        <th ng-click="order('city')">City</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="kid in person | filter:filter_by | orderBy:sort_by:reverse">

        <td ng-if=" kid.gender == $scope.gender">
            {{kid.name}}
        </td>
        <td ng-if=" kid.gender == $scope.gender">
            {{kid.gender}}
        </td>
        <td ng-if=" kid.gender == $scope.gender">
            {{kid.city}}
        </td>
        <td ng-if="$scope.gender=='A'">
            {{kid.name}}
        </td>
        <td ng-if="$scope.gender=='A'">
            {{kid.gender}}
        </td>
        <td ng-if="$scope.gender=='A'">
            {{kid.city}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

There is no directory issue. The scripts are in the correct folder. I don't know why this isn't working. Id appreciate any and all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rearange the loading order of your scripts:

It should be like this:

```
<script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/controllers/new_Controller.js"></script>
```

Comment: now im getting a failed to load template error on people.html
thank you for pointing that out. I didnt know that the order between the controller and the main app file mattered.

Comment: How does your folder structure look like? What are the full URLs used?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still a beginner at this, but with routing I've found there's always some 'magic stuff' I always have to do:

- Add the base element to the header
- Set the location provider to use html5Mode

To add the base element to your header, put this at the top of app.js:

```
var windowLocation = window.location.pathname;
var baseElementText = "<base href='" + windowLocation + "'/>";
var baseElement = angular.element(baseText);
angular.element(document.querySelector('head')).append(baseElement);
```

To set the locationProvider to use html5Mode

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',{
            controller: 'Controller_people',
            templateUrl: '/app/views/people.html'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});

   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Also, a good test is to confirm that your `when` is actually matching. What happens if you do this..

```
$routeProvider.otherwise({
             controller: 'Controller_people',
             templateUrl: '/app/views/people.html'
          });
```

If the view displays, then at least you will know that the routing framework is working.